# Строка не содержит управляющих ASCII символов

Tags: c#, строки, ascii

Есть строка, в которой есть цифры, буквы и знаки препинания. Например: г. Москва, ул. Ленина д.5. Надо проверить, есть ли в ней символы, относящиеся к управляющим символам ASCII таблицы(коды с 0х00 до 0х1F и 0x7F).

Вообще не могу понять как в моей строке искать эти символы. Не перечислять же мне их вручную, а потом посимвольно сравнивать...

Comment: Нужен результат true / false? Можно использовать `s.Any(c => c >= 0 && c <= 31)` для этого. Или нужно вывести все эти символы? (`s.Where(c => c >= 0 && c <= 31).ToList()`). Тут ещё вопрос: как быть с символами перевода строки и табуляцией?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Можно и true false. Мне главное найти, если есть в строке символы из этого диапазона, то я эту строку откидываю. Про табуляцию, в тех. задании указан диапазон ASCII символов с 0х00 до 0х1F и 0х7F. Все остальные я пропускаю без каких-либо проверок.

Comment: Т.е. 0х7F тоже нужно учесть, ясно.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, 0x7F добавил в шапку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Надо проверить, есть ли в ней символы, относящиеся к управляющим символам ASCII таблицы(коды с 0х00 до 0х1F).

`Char.IsControl` тут не подойдёт, так как этот метод проверяет также наличие управляющих символов всей таблицы Юникода.

Нужно использовать LINQ. `s.Any(c => (c >= 0 && c <= 31) || c == 127)` проверит наличие требуемых символов в тексте, а `s.Where(c => (c >= 0 && c <= 31) || c == 127).ToList()` вернёт их список:

```
var s = "\x08   \n\r";
var result = s.Any(c => (c >= 0 && c <= 31) || c == 127);
Console.WriteLine(result); // => True
var result2 = s.Where(c => (c >= 0 && c <= 31) || c == 127).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", string.Join("';'", result2));
```

Result:

```
True
'';'    ';'
';'
'
```

[См. демо](http://ideone.com/v17PA3)

Можно и регулярным выражением:

```
var hasAsciiControlChr = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"[\u0000-\u001F\u007F]");
```

См. [C#-демо](http://ideone.com/99LAE0).